# How to run a utils POD on K8S which doesn't run a process

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have this docker image which has many useful tools installed. I use it inside docker to debug stuff, like testing connections to other containers. Now I would like to use this image in Kubernetes. However, because it doesn't run a process the pod will not start

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN .... useful tools ...
```

And the kubernetes file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: uitls
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      bar: utils-xxl
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        bar: utils-xxl
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: utils
        image: jeanluca/base
```

When I try to apply this the pod it ends up in the `CrashLoopBackOff` state. Is there a way in kubernetes to start this pod? Maybe with `exec` and `bash`? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [`kubectl run`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#run) a one-off pod for interactive debugging.

```
kubectl run jeanluca-debug \
  --generator=run-pod/v1 \
  --rm -it \
  --image=jeanluca/base
```

This is basically equivalent to a `docker run` command with the same options, except that the pod name is a required positional parameter.

This technique is useful for the sorts of debugging tasks you describe.  If your image has tools like `redis-cli`, a `mysql` or `psql` client, DNS lookup tools like `host` or `dig`, and so on, it can be useful to figure out why exactly your combined system is broken.  The image's default command can be `CMD ["/bin/bash"]` and that's fine, but it will exit immediately if it doesn't have an input stream attached, so you need to run it via `kubectl run` like this instead of trying to get a Deployment to keep it alive.

In general there's no point to keeping a container or pod running that's doing literally nothing.  There are certainly tricks to keep a Docker container from exiting but I'd suggest avoiding them.

Answer (score 3):

If you want an always up pod that you can use for exec-ing into and running commands, you can just tell the container to open a shell and sleep.

Something like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: uitls
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      bar: utils-xxl
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        bar: utils-xxl
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: utils
        image: jeanluca/base
        command: ["/bin/sh"]
        args: ["-c", "while true; sleep 999; done"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

- Add `CMD tail -f /dev/null` at the end of your `dockerfile`. In this case the same deployment yaml should work.

OR

- Modify your k8s deployment.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: uitls
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      bar: utils-xxl
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        bar: utils-xxl
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: utils
        image: jeanluca/base
        command: ["tail"]
        args: ["-f", "/dev/null"]
```

OR

- Run a container in k8s like `docker run` using `kubectl run` refer [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/docker-cli-to-kubectl/#docker-run).